# Accessing request.json in Flask results in an exception

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

I'm using Flask 0.10.1, and I have a Flask function that starts like this:

```
@app.route('/logs', methods=['POST'])
def add_log():
    db = get_db()

    print("\ninside /logs POST\n===================")
    print(request.headers)

    print('--------------')
    print(request.form)

    print('--------------')
    try:
        print(request.json)
    except Exception as e:
        print('SOMETHING REAL BAD HAPPENED')
        print(e)

    if not request.json:
        print("abandon ship!")
        abort(400)
```

I'm making an ajax request to this location via JQuery:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: '/logs',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'body': 'you know that i could use some body', 'tags': 'tagggssss'},
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
```

It appears that immediately upon trying to access request.json, the Flask functoin fails. Here's the Flask server output:

```
inside /logs POST
===================
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:5000/
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 55
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Cache-Control: no-cache


--------------
ImmutableMultiDict([])
--------------
SOMETHING REAL BAD HAPPENED
400: Bad Request
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2014 13:16:30] "POST /logs HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

The Flask docs state:

> If the mimetype is application/json this [request.json, if I understand correctly] will contain the parsed JSON data. Otherwise this will be None.

This leads me to believe that parsing the JSON is somehow failing, though I'm not sure how that could be. How can I see what the problem is?

Comment: Since the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/?highlight=request.json#flask.Request.json) say _The [get_json()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/?highlight=request.json#flask.Request.get_json) method should be used instead_, have you tried using that instead?

Comment: I actually did try that (assuming that I can just replace every 'request.json' with 'request.get_json()'.) I get exactly the same error.

Comment: Can you try `data: JSON.stringify({body: 'you know that i could use some body', tags: 'tagggssss'}),` in your request?

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually posting JSON; only your mimetype claims you are. Use `JSON.stringify()`:

```
  data: JSON.stringify({'body': 'you know that i could use some body', 'tags': 'tagggssss'}),
```